# How do I print once in a while loop but still have the while loop run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reddit Bot Question: I'm trying to see if any comment has the phrase "Hello There." in it and if it doesn't have "Hello There." in it, I want it to print "Nothing Found." once and wait until a comment is found. It works like a charm but instead of printing "Nothing Found." once and waiting for another comment, it prints "Nothing Found." repeatedly for an infinite amount of time until a comment comes. I've tried multiple options and ways from multiple forums but I can't seem to get this correct. Here is the code:

```
def run_bot():
        while True:
            for comment in r.subreddit("test").comments(limit=10):
                comment_text = comment.body.lower()
                isMatch = any(string in comment_text for string in words_match)
                if comment.id not in cache and isMatch and comment.author != r.user.me():
                        comment.reply("[GENERAL KENOBI!](https://youtu.be/rEq1Z0bjdwc)\n\n^(*I am a bot, and this action was performed automatically.*)")
                        print(comment.id)
                        cache.append(comment.id)
                        with open("commentcache.txt", "a") as f:
                            f.write(comment.id + "\n")
                        print("Resetting in:")
                        def countdown(n):
                            while n > 0:
                                print (n, "...")
                                n = n - 1
                                time.sleep(1)
                                if n ==0:
                                    print("Reset Successful!")
                                    time.sleep(1)
                        countdown(5)
                    else:
                        print("Nothing Found.")


    def saved():
        if not os.path.isfile("commentcache.txt"):
            commentcache = []
        else:
            with open("commentcache.txt", "r") as f:
                commentcache = f.read
                commentcache = commentcache().split("\n")
                commentcache = list(filter(None, commentcache))
        return commentcache

    cache = saved()
    print(cache)
    run_bot()
```

The trouble starts at:

```
else:
    print("Nothing Found.")
```

it prints that infinitely.

Comment: Your indentation is broken. The `else` does not match any outer `if`. And the `def saved` is also at a wrong indentation level.

Comment: You have no `time.sleep` command in the `else`, so what did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably a boolean flag:

```
print_status = True
while True:
    ...
    if isMatch and ...:
        comment.reply("[GENERAL KENOBI!] ...")
        ...
        print_status = True
    elif print_status:
        print("Nothing found")
        print_status = False
```